# Passing a file to DLV in cmd

Tags: answer-set-programming

I have a program written in a text file and I want to execute this file using dlv in the command prompt, however it keeps returning this error:

heba.txt: line 0: can't open input.

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What exactly is "dlv"?

Comment: DLV is a deductive database system, based on disjunctive logic programming, which offers front-ends to several advanced KR formalisms.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not a problem with `dlv` but with your console/terminal.
Depending on your operating system etc.. i would guess that you first have to switch to the directory that contains your file `heba.txt`. Search for command like `cd` `list` `dir` depending on your operating system.

Comment: I have added the correct path to the cmd and I got the correct version of the dlv as: C:\Users\hebaw>Downloads\datalog\dlv.exe
DLV [build BEN/Dec 17 2012   gcc 4.6.1]

usage: Downloads\datalog\dlv.exe {FRONTEND} {OPTIONS} [filename [filename [...]]]

Specify -help for more detailed usage information. however when I try to run the file ,txt using dlv it return the following error: C:\Users\hebaw>Downloads\datalog\dlv heba.txt
DLV [build BEN/Dec 17 2012   gcc 4.6.1]

heba.txt: line 0: can't open input.
{}